# Javascript - Do something when an element in two arrays are the same?

Tags: javascript

I found a solution to where I get returned an array of elements without duplicates:

```
Array1 = Array1.filter(function(val) {
  return Array2.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
```

However, I want to modify this code just a little bit. Instead of being returned an array without duplicates, I want to do something when there is a duplicate. The problem is, I'm not sure how exactly this code works. The thing is I'm not sure how `val` gets set, or what it even is.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { 
    var item = json[i];
    // if json.indexOf(val?), do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs for the Array `filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) then. The `val` parameter of the callback will be passed the single array items, i.e. `json[i]` or `item` in your case:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) { 
    var item = json[i];
    if (json.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = array1.filter(function(v, i) {
    return array1.indexOf(v) == i;
});
```

This will return only unique itesm from array1;

```
array1.filter(function(v, i) {
    // write your code here ('v' is individual value and 'i' is its index)
    // don't return any anything if you don't want unique array to be returned.
    // 'array1.indexOf(v) == i' checks if current value is duplicate from previous any values.
    // try putting console.log on values you don't understand like (console.log(v,i) for values of 'v' and 'i')
    return array1.indexOf(v) == i;
});
```

and off-curse you can loop an array with for loop as

```
for(i in array1){
    // where i is index of array1, to get current value use array1[i]
    if(array2.indexOf(array1[i]) >= 0){
        // do something
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`val` is set by [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which calls the callback function on each element in the array. Since you don't want to filter you can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead, which also calls the callback function once for each element in the array:

```
Array1.forEach(
  // This function is called once per element in Array1
  function(val){
    if(Array2.indexOf(val) != -1){ // Check if that element is also in Array2
        // `val` is in both arrays,
        // Do something with it
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize some modern libraries... like underscorejs.

Intersection is what you're looking for i guess: http://underscorejs.org/#intersection

```
_.intersection([1, 2, 3], [101, 2, 1, 10], [2, 1]);
=> [1, 2]
```

So your code may be something like

```
if(_.insersection(arr1, arr2)){
  //since [] array is Falsy in JS this will work as a charm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN: indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> Returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

From [MDN: filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> Creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The first function works by returning `true` when an item from array1 isn't found in array2 (== -1). i.e.: Iterate through A and add anything not found in B.

So, to change to return only duplicates return `true` for anything that is found in both:

```
Array1 = Array1.filter(function(val) {
    return Array2.indexOf(val) >= 0;
});
```

Array1 now contains only items with duplicates.